# Determine when random notification is dismissed, or when a PendingIntent is fired

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a program where i do specific things when `Notifications` are displayed and dismissed. These notifications are NOT from this application but others.

To capture notifications i am using an `AccessibilityService`, with this i am able to see when a notification is displayed but not dismissed. I am also able to get a reference to the Notification and as such its `PendingIntent` for when it is dismissed.

My question, is there any way to determine when a notification(that i did not create) is dismissed, or when a PendingIntent goes off?

Answer (score 0):

Not really... You can't tell whether one of your own Notifications has been dismissed, or is still displayed, I don't know of a way to tell if someone else's notification is still there.

Comment: You can tell if one of your own Notifications has been dismissed/still displayed. There are at least 2 methods, not least of which is the official way of using the deleteIntent.

Comment: Uh, could you elaborate? Once you create the notification and add it to the notification manager it's not possible to get a reference to it again...